# SFML 3.0 'intersects' function

Tags: c++, sfml

I downloaded the latest `SFML 3.0` source code from github and compiled it using MinGW GCC 11.2 on Windows 10. I'm try to compile example programs from **SFML Essentials** book.

The code below causes compilation error:

```
if(playerRect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(targetRect.getGlobalBounds()))
    window.close();
```

```
error: 'using FloatRect = class sf::Rect<float>' {aka 'class sf::Rect<float>'} has no member named 'intersects'
   43 |         if(playerRect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(targetRect.getGlobalBounds()))
```

Looks like there are some breaking changes between `SFML 2.5.1` and `SFML 3.0` but these changes are not listed on SFML website.

Could someone please let me know how to compile the above code and also point me to any resource which highlights the difference between `SFML 2.5.1` and `SFML 3.0`.

Thanks

Comment: Use `findIntersection`, taken from [rect class code](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/Rect.hpp).

Comment: @rafix07, `findIntersection` worked, thanks. Do you know of any document which highlights the changes between 2.5.1 & 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are API changes in `SFML 3.0` which are not compatible with `SFML 2.5`. For example `VideoMode` constructor is defined as follows:

```
// SFML 2.5
VideoMode(unsigned int modeWidth, unsigned int modeHeight, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);

// SFML 3.0
explicit VideoMode(const Vector2u& modeSize, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
```

Hence the below code compiles fine using `SFML 2.5` but throws an error when `SFML 3.0` is used.

```
// compiles fine with SFML 2.5
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML-Test");  

// Gives following error in SFML 3.0
// error: no matching function for call to 'sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(int, int)'
```

The table below summaries the changes required to port an application from `SFML 2.5` to `SFML 3.0`.

| SFML 2.5 | SFML 3.0 |
| --- | --- |
| `sf::VideoMode(640, 480)` | `sf::VideoMode({640,480})` |
| `shape.setOrigin(0, 0)` | `shape.setOrigin({0, 0})` |
| `shape.setPosition(0, 0)` | `shape.setPosition({0, 0})` |
| `shape.setRotation(90.)` | `shape.setRotation(sf::degrees(90.f))` |
| `rect1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(rect2.getGlobalBounds())` | `rect1.getGlobalBounds().findIntersection(rect2.getGlobalBounds())` |

The above list is non-exhaustive. I've listed only things which I've learned so far using `SFML 3.0`.

Also in `SFML 3.0`, if we ignore the return value of `Texture::loadFromImage`, we get a nice warning message, thanks to C++17 `[[nodiscard]]` attribute.

```
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromImage("sprite.png");  // no warning in SFML 2.5

// SFML 3.0 gives following warning
// warning: ignoring return value of 'bool sf::Texture::loadFromFile(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&, const IntRect&)', declared with attribute 'nodiscard'
```

Also note that `sf::Mutex` and `sf::Lock` are no longer supported. They should be replaced with C++11 `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`.

Hope this helps someone who want to port their application from SFML 2.5/2.6 to SFML 3.0.